# How to fix md-tabs and md-toolbar and scroll md-content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<md-tabs>
  <md-tab label="First Tab">
    <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
    <md-content>
      <md-list>
        <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
          <md-item-content>
            <div>
              {{item}}
            </div>
          </md-item-content>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </md-content>

  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Second tab">
    <md-list flex>
      <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
        <md-item-content>{{item}}</md-item-content>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

I want the tabs and toolbar to be fixed (always visible) and the contents of the list to scroll. I can't find a way to do that. There are other similar issues reported (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319282/angular-material-md-tabs-and-md-grid-lists)) but they seem to be old and supposedly fixed. I am working with angular-material 0.10.0

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ZkDIQFunka9MMtrr2pd?p=preview)

Comment: did u find a solution ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with a little CSS.

```
Add a class to the elements with position:fixed !important
```

Don't forget to use !important . This will override the default position property for tabs and toolbar

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpfull for you

```
<body layout="column">
  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2>
        <span>Toolbar</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs>
    <md-tab>
      <md-tab-label>
        Tab 1
      </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab>
      <md-tab-label>
        Tab 2
      </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
  <md-content flex>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    Hello world
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Comment: That works if you add an <md-content> for each tab. The issue is that the content doesn't benefit from the animations that <md-tab-body> within <md-tab> provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "`md-subheader`" as a parent container. Its default behavior is sticky. Its documentation is https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSubheader

I'm not sure if this is a bad or good approach but I couldn't found any alternative way in angular material 1.1.0 (RC4).